# zsh command cannot found pip

Tags: pip, oh-my-zsh

How can I use `pip` in oh-my-zsh? I was trying to install `nltk` through pip, but it told me `zsh: command not found: pip`. When I check plugins under `.oh-my-zsh/custom/plugins`, there is a folder named `pip`. I don't know what the problem is.

**Edit**:

```bash
$ echo $PATH
/home/xxx/bin:/usr/local/bin:/home/xxx/bin:/home/xxx/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

$ type pip
pip is an alias for noglob pip
```

Comment: Can you access `pip` from Bash?

Comment: Sure, I have been using `pip` to install python packages from bash.

Comment: And you can still access 'pip' from Bash? I'm only asking because I think there might a problem with your PATH variable.

Comment: Could you edit the question to include the value of 'echo $PATH' from both shells and 'type pip' from Bash?

Comment: Follow this stackoverflow post to replace the need to type "pip3" with "pip" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44455001/how-to-change-pip3-command-to-be-pip

Answer (score 330, accepted):

Maybe you have installed both `python2` and `python3`. `python3` may have been installed later.

You may try to use `pip3` instead of `pip`.

First, input the command:

```bash
pip3 -V
```

If you see the version, the `pip3` can be used.

Then you can input command line to install `nltk`:

```bash
pip3 install nltk
```

---

I got a way to help you use pip in zsh. *We can use `nano` to edit files. In nano, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to save and exit*

In the `~` directory, input the command:

```bash
nano .bash_profile
```

You may see some codes like:

```bash
# Setting PATH for Python 3.5
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

Copy them and paste them to the end of `.zshrc` file by using command:

```bash
nano .zshrc
```

Then input the command:

```bash
pip -V
```

If you see the version, `pip` can be used.

Comment: Since I am using Anaconda, I added `export PATH="/home/gejun/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"` to .zshrc  and it works for me. Thanks!

Comment: I did it and I have both versions and it didn't work for me. Not `pip` nor `pip3` are recognized.

Comment: had the same issue. pip3 worked, instead of pip. Thanks!

Answer (score 59):

In case you do

```
which pip
```

and it doesn't show the path, just do

```
which pip3
```

This will print the path which is `/usr/local/bin/pip3`
Then do `open ~/.zshrc` or `nano ~/.bash_profile`.

Make alias for pip like:

```
alias pip=/usr/local/bin/pip3
```

N.B: You copy that line above and paste in your `.zshrc` file.

After do `source ~/.zshrc` and close `.zshrc`

Comment: Note: You can also run this command line to copy to your `.zshrc` file

```echo "alias python=/usr/bin/pip3" >> ~/.zshrc```

Then restart your terminal

Answer (score 29):

So you are using `oh-my-zsh` framework for `zsh`  or Z shell.
First, try the command:

```
pip3 -V
```

If you get something like this below, that means you have the pip3 package already and must be having python3 as well.

```
pip 22.0.4 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip (python 3.10)
```

Then edit your .zprofile instead of .bashprofile as you are using zsh. This is the command.

```
nano ~/.zprofile
```

Then it should have the two alias like this.

```
# Setting PATH for Python 3.10
# The original version is saved in .zprofile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

alias python=python3
alias pip=pip3
```

Make sure you save it. Exit and Re-open you terminal. Type the command:

```
pip -V
```

It should have the same result as the `pip3 -V` like this:

```
❯ pip -V
pip 22.0.4 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip (python 3.10)
```

Then you can use `pip` or `pip3` interchangeably for installing your `nltk` package like this.

```
pip install nltk
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for – thanks! To anyone else who sees this comment, you may need to restart terminal for the changes to take effect

Comment: Thank you! The answer that I've been struggling to find

Answer (score 23):

For me it's working to do

```
python -m pip install [package_name]
```

instead of

```
pip install [package_name]
```

Comment: You can add an alias to your shell if you update` ~/.zshrc` file. Something like `alias pip=/usr/local/bin/pip3`

That will then allow you to run the pip command directly without calling python first

Answer (score 21):

If you installed `python3.x`, you should run with `pip3`(not `pip`)

Answer (score 12):

I'm on MacOS and use ZSH. It seems pip 2.7 can't be found, although it is installed. I believe my paths to "pip" are linked wrong (I also have python3 and pip3 installed via brew).

To get around the issue I created an alias. If you don't have an .aliases file, create one in your homedir. Then open the file:

```
nano ~/.aliases
```

and add:

```
## PIP for python2.7 ##
alias pip="python -m pip "
```

You need to tell ZSH to pick up the alias file (assuming you don't have this setup already). Open your .zshrc:

```
nano ~/.zshrc
```

The add the following near the bottom of the file:

```
[ -f "$HOME/.aliases" ] && source "$HOME/.aliases"
```

From the terminal, run:

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

Or quit your terminal and reopen it.

Now you can run:

```
pip install <command>
```

Comment: I just added this alias to my .zshrc file: "alias pip3="python3 -m pip"". Why did you separate out the aliases into a separate file?

Answer (score 8):

Edit your rc file:

```bash
vim ~/.zshrc
```

Find the config plugins and delete the `pip` entry.

In a new terminal:

```bash
which pip
```

This will show you the real path of `pip`

Comment: This is what worked for me! I also added the following to `~/.zshrc`: `alias pip=/usr/local/bin/pip3`

Comment: It didn't work for me, even after `source`ing `~/.zshrc`.

Answer (score 3):

If you're running into this issue, it probably is due to versioning complications. Python 2 versus Python 3 on your OS may be resolving unexpectedly. Below is a quick workaround to get you to functioning behavior.

Try using the below for Python 2:
`python -m pip install <command>`

Try using the below for Python 3:
`pip3 install <command>`

Comment: They key here is using pip3 command especially if you have installed Python 3. It worked for me after hours of online searching, thanks Chioke.

Answer (score 1):

In my case my OS was Ubuntu 20.04 and the pip doesn't come with python.

So, i've installed pip through the command

***sudo apt install python3-pip***

and I'm done.

To ensure run `pip -V` or `pip3 -V`

Answer (score 0):

My pip script is missing for some reason, so I have to install it.

```
$ python -m ensurepip --upgrade
```

More methods can be found here:[pip installation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/)

Answer (score 0):

You should consider upgrading.

Enter this in your terminal

*/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3.10 -m pip install --upgrade pip*

and then...

Type: pip -V