# How do I install pandas for Python using IDLE or terminal?

Tags: python, pandas, terminal, pip, python-idle

I have been having issues installing pandas for Python.  I use python in both IDLE and terminal and my computer is a Mac if this is relevant.  I have tried the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
pip install pandas
pip install pip
$ pip install pandas
import pandas as pd
```

and I always receive error messages.  What do I need to do to get this to work?

Note: I am very new to python.

Error messages in IDLE:

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Error messages in terminal:

> [me] is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
> zsh: command not found: pip
> zsh: command not found: pip
> zsh: command not found: $
> zsh: command not found: import

Comment: First off, warm welcome to Stack Overflow. But secondly, it would be pretty useful if you would show exactly what error messages you're getting; it'll be difficult to diagnose the problem without them

Comment: Thanks.  I just edited my question to include the error messages.

Comment: These were all very helpful.  Thank you.

Comment: UPDATE: I have downloaded pandas with the pip3, but am still receiving the "zsh: command not found: import" error message.

Comment: Are you trying to use ```import``` directly on the command line? The ```import``` command needs to go in the .py file that you're trying to run, not on the command line; try putting ```import pandas as pd``` at the top of your .py file with whatever your text editor of choice is (nano, vim, or in the .py file creator in IDLE)

Comment: I'll try that.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things in the wrong here.

> [me] is not in the sudoers file. This incident will be reported

Are you logged in as a admin user on your Mac? If not, you'll need to do so to run commands with the prefix "sudo"

> zsh: command not found: pip zsh: command not found: pip zsh: command
> not found: $ zsh: command not found: import

It seems like python and pip are not set up properly on your mac. Please follow this guide to set up Python on your system: https://opensource.com/article/19/5/python-3-default-mac

Answer (score 0):

[zsh command cannot found pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42870537/zsh-command-cannot-found-pip)

The linked thread seems to discuss a pretty similar problem to your own. To give a summary, it's entirely possible that you have python2 and python3 installed. Try running the command:

```
pip3 -V
```

If you see a version come up, then you can use `pip3` instead of `pip`, and use the command `pip3 install pandas`. There are some other solutions in the linked thread as well.