# Why am I getting this error while trying to install play sound using pip on the terminal?

Tags: python, error-handling, playsound

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2EEc.png)

I am a newbie to Python. I tried installing a external module using pip on the terminal of python in VS CODE. I use a MacOs laptop to code.
What can be done here?

Also, feel free to add links/names of resources to coding info and tips.

I tried some ideas given in in the screenshot above.

I tried what was suggested in the comments. It is not installing
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdaPE.png)

pip3 seems to be the thing but, still the installation isn't going through.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dz2fR.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HR2iT.png)

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow! You have additional characters before your command. Just type `pip install playsound` without the `/` or the `> `.

Comment: I did it. Still it hasn't downloaded! I have added an image above to my original question for you to see.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [zsh command cannot found pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42870537/zsh-command-cannot-found-pip)

Comment: I checked out the question blog you had tagged @dkasa I even entered the command as given by the top comment, still there is some error. I have added pictures to my original question.